# Visual Studio Intellisense for Bootstrap does not work in a Node project?

Tags: css, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I've created ASP.net MVC projects before and the Intellisense worked just fine for the Bootstrap CSS in Visual Studio 2013.

I wanted to try using Visual Studio for Node projects as well as I love the IDE, so I downloaded it, which required Visual Studio 2015 but I can't get the Intellisense to work for Bootstrap CSS.

I tried googling and didn't find much.  I did go to the Options --> Text Editor --> Javascript --> Intellisense --> References --> added "bootstrap.js" but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Hi, do you means when you edit in the bootstrap css file, the intellisense not works? It is better to provide the detail information or screenshot to show your current issue. Since it works fine in VS 2013 MVC project, you can also have a test in the VS 2015 MVC project, it can help you to excludes this issue is only occurred in Node JS project or not.

Comment: If after reference bootstrap and the intellisense like class not works, make sure they are under the same folder, you can have a try with install bootstrap Bundle/Snippet Pack through Tools-Extensions and Updates-Online or reference Bootstrap using Bower.